# How to update global variables inside a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, soundcloud

I am trying to get data from SoundCloud API. I do it successfully, but the problem is that the data I get are only saved inside the scope and the variable stays 'undefined' outside the scope. [JSFiddle](http://goo.gl/kOS3DT)

```
$.fn.greenify = function() {

    var trackURL = this.text();
    this.empty();
    var title, id;
    SC.get('/resolve', { url: trackURL }, function (track) {
        title = track.title; //track title
        id = track.id;
    });
    $(this).text(title); // title is undefined
    console.log(title);

};

$( "a" ).greenify(); // Makes all the links green.
$( "div" ).greenify();
```

So each html element must get the corresponding track title as text. But that doesn't happen because `$(this).text(title);` applies nothing.

Any idea?

Comment: Because `SC.get` is not synchronous. Do the `console.log()` inside `SC.get` to see the value. But the code in `SC.get` runs afterwards.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/x2y8o66d/1/